# Why is my second function not working ? (Started coding this week)

Tags: javascript, html

Im want to calculate the change. But I only get the error "Nan"

I want to code a cash system.

```html
<script>
  function alles() {
    var field1 = document.getElementById("1").value;
    var field2 = document.getElementById("2").value;
    var field3 = document.getElementById("3").value;
    var field4 = document.getElementById("4").value;
    var field5 = document.getElementById("5").value;
    var field6 = document.getElementById("6").value;

    var result = parseInt(field1) * parseInt(field2) + parseInt(field3) * parseInt(field4) + parseInt(field5) * parseInt(field6);
    document.getElementById("9").innerHTML = parseInt(+result);
  }
</script>

<div class="Gesamt">
  <p align="left">
    <font size="5" face "Arial">DOM
      <font>
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Amount 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="1"></td>
      <td>Price 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amount 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="3"></td>
      <td>Price 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amount 3
        <td>
          <td><input type="number" id="5"></td>
          <td>Price 3</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="6"></td>
    </tr>


  </table>
  <p>
    <h3 id="9"></h3>
    <button onclick="alles()">Total price</button>


  </p>
</div>



<div class="Wechsel">
  <h3 id="a"></h3>
  To pay <input type="number" id="b" value=0>


  <br>

  <button onclick="calculate()">change</button>
</div>
<script>
  function calculate() {

    var field7 = document.getElementById("9").value;
    var field8 = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var result = parseInt(field7) - parseInt(field8);
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = parseInt(+result);
  }
</script>

</body>
```

I expect the output of the second function to be the 
difference from "id=9" and "id=b"

Comment: Some abilities are incorrect - User is new to community, at least let him/ her know why you down voted this one where it's clearly written that He just started practising this week. Be humble that will help

Comment: h3 elements dont have a value property (your id=9 element), use innerText

Comment: `NaN` is not an error, it's a value.

Comment: The element with ID 9 is a h3, not an input. If you gave your elements sensible identifiers it would be much easier to spot your mistakes.

Comment: @NilsKw you error is you are trying to get the value from id 9 by using innerHtml which just show the data (basically return A String, representing the HTML content of an element) .Rather use document.getElementById("9").innerText (The innerText property sets or returns the text content of the specified node, and all its descendants.)  Refer link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp more clear concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var field7 = document.getElementById("9").value;
```

to (because field7 is not an `input`)

```
var field7 = document.getElementById("9").innerText;
```

```html
<script>
  function alles() {
    var field1 = document.getElementById("1").value;
    var field2 = document.getElementById("2").value;
    var field3 = document.getElementById("3").value;
    var field4 = document.getElementById("4").value;
    var field5 = document.getElementById("5").value;
    var field6 = document.getElementById("6").value;

    var result = parseInt(field1) * parseInt(field2) + parseInt(field3) * parseInt(field4) + parseInt(field5) * parseInt(field6);
    document.getElementById("9").innerHTML = parseInt(+result);
  }
</script>

<div class="Gesamt">
  <p align="left">
    <font size="5" face "Arial">DOM
      <font>
  </p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Amount 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="1"></td>
      <td>Price 1</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amount 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="3"></td>
      <td>Price 2</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Amount 3
        <td>
          <td><input type="number" id="5"></td>
          <td>Price 3</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="6"></td>
    </tr>


  </table>
  <p>
    <h3 id="9"></h3>
    <button onclick="alles()">Total price</button>


  </p>
</div>



<div class="Wechsel">
  <h3 id="a"></h3>
  To pay <input type="number" id="b" value=0>


  <br>

  <button onclick="calculate()">change</button>
</div>
<script>
  function calculate() {

    var field7 = document.getElementById("9").innerText;
    var field8 = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var result = parseInt(field7) - parseInt(field8);
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = parseInt(+result);
  }
</script>

</body>
```

Consider also to not use `id` attribute (with `getElementById`) but rather `class` or `name` (with [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector))